# setting the create date of a file

Tags: windows, file-attributes, filetime

I have a folder full of mp3 files. They are named consecutively *01.mp3* through *86.mp3*. They currently all have the same create_date. I need them to all have different create_dates, preferably a day apart. What the create date is doesn't really matter as long as the create dates are in the same direction as the file name number. I'm pretty fluent in PHP but that's really my only language. I actually got a php script that set the modify date but that doesn't work for what I need. I found a utility that would let me change the create date but it was a gui and I could only change 1 file at a time. I need it to be a batch process. Any ideas?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Oh yeah, windows 7, but I can move them to xp if easier. I suppose I could find a linux box as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a utility called FileTouch. It lets you modify the create date, among other things, through a command line interface. I just used excel to build a series of commands that set the create date of each file a day apart and saved it as a batch file as so.

```
... 
FileTouch /C /D 01-01-2010 24.mp3
FileTouch /C /D 01-02-2010 25.mp3
FileTouch /C /D 01-03-2010 26.mp3
...
```